# WORDPRESS: Find the code you found by inspect (F12) but in your public_html

Tags: wordpress

I'm sorry if the title is confusing but i could not make up any better.

So my question: I see my nice looking wordpress-site, I want to change one particular part so i press F12 and find it while inspect, but when I try to locate it in my public_html it is extremly time consuming to find it (if I *ever* do it).

What am I doing wrong? There must be something I miss here, right? What is the best practice when you want to change something minor in your site?

Answer (score 0):

install **"whatTheFile"** plugin in your site and activate it.
you should now see the files of the pages you visit at the top admin bar as you are logged in as Admin of course.
Get the file name then go look for it in the FTP side using the file manager of the Cpanel for example or simply by using **FileZila** if you have the FTP coordinates of your host.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to find the files of the active theme inside of `public_html`. They should be in `wp-content` -> `themes`.

Once you find the theme, if you're going to be modifying its files, you should really [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) first, or else you'll loose your changes when the theme updates.

You should then familiarize yourself with the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) so you'll know which of the php files of the theme are used to render which pages.
Alternatively/additionally as mentioned already, you could also use a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) to help you find the file which is being used to render the page.

This all may sound like a lot of work for something "minor", but better to do it right from the beginning. Next time you'll want to change more things, it'll be much easier and better.

Comment: Thank you so much for those advices. It was a lot to learn but as you said, better do it the right way from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a localhost site on my desktop with the same theme & plugins.  Then using something like notepad++ I can vae the editor do a global search in all php files for the text.  Bear in mind that some of the text may have been dynamically generated so choose what to search for carefully - exclude text that may have been dynamically generated even if it means you get more results back.

As others have said above if you know what is probably generating the text (a theme template or a plugin shortcode) you can speed up the search by only searching within those subset of files.

THEN depending what it is you want to change, check whether you can do it in a way where you are NOT changing the original code.  That way theme and plugin updates can still be applied :

- is it filtereable - ie you see an apply_filter in the code, then
  rather filter it.
- or translateable text?
- or a pluggable function?
- or a child theme with the template part that you are changing
- or if it is some content within a css selector, maybe just using css to swop the content?